# iOS how to create animating buttons similar to Twitter heart button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uibutton

I have created custom buttons and worked with custom UIViews in the past. However I am not sure how to go about with this.

I am trying to create something similar to the twitter heart animation.
What I am unable to get is those tiny colored circles around the heart as shown in this gif:

https://dribbble.com/shots/2416983-Twitter-Heart-Animation

Any ideas?

Also is it possible for me to simply have a gif and add the gif as a custom view in a UIButton and play the gif when button is pressed?

Comment: animateKeyFramesWithDuration would probably get you 90% of this effect.

Comment: @ncke thanks, do you know how to create the bubbles?

Comment: Maybe use a UIView with 16x16 size and layer.cornerRadius set to 8.

Comment: @ncke so I will be created a rounded UIView for each bubble and animate the movement outside?

Comment: Yes. Just an idea. The bubbles would be subviews of the heart, you could do the motion - stop - fade thing as key frames.

Comment: https://github.com/xhamr/fave-button

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concept:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
```

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIView *bubble = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0)];
    bubble.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
    bubble.center = self.view.center;
    bubble.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:bubble];

    UIView *heart = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
    heart.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
    heart.center = self.view.center;
    heart.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:heart];

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0
                                   delay:0.0
                                 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat
                              animations:^{

                                  // Heart expands
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.10 animations:^{
                                      heart.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
                                  }];

                                  // Heart contracts.
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.15 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                                      heart.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                                  }];

                                  // Bubble travels.
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.4 animations:^{
                                      CGPoint destination = self.view.center;
                                      destination.x += 100;
                                      destination.y -= 100;
                                      bubble.center = destination;
                                  }];

                                  // Bubble shrinks.
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.6 relativeDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                                      bubble.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3, 0.3);
                                  }];

                                  // Bubble fades.
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.8 relativeDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                                      bubble.alpha = 0.0;
                                  }];

                              } completion:nil];
}

To get the full effect, you will need to add any a few more key frames so the bubble curves around before the fade. Given that you have a couple of bubbles, it might be a good idea to create a key frame generator.

Comment: thank you very much! I will give it a try and update back in couple days

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use SKEmitterNode and add real particles to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer but useful to other developers.
Here is the Link for exact same animation: https://github.com/xhamr/fave-button

Same Animation in Objective-C also: https://github.com/tljackyi/fave-button

Comment: Hi Mitul, do you know how to use the animation in  Objective C https://github.com/tljackyi/fave-button? I am bit confused on how to add the favicon to my VC. There is no tapped function for me to add codes to it and I don't even know how to place it at the Navigation Bar, please help.